# IllegalArgumentException - при отправке mail

Tags: java, spring, sendmail

На джаве пытаюсь написать модуль для отправки уведомления на спринге сделал такой контекстный файл

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="someHost"/>
        <property name="port" value="25"/>
        <property name="username" value="someMail"/>
        <property name="password" value="somePassword"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
        <property name="from" value="someMail"/>
        <property name="subject" value="Уведомление"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailNotificationService" class="kz.ivc.notificator.MailNotificationService" autowire="byName" />
```

и сам метод

```
@Resource(name="mailSender")
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Resource(name="templateMessage")
    private SimpleMailMessage messageTemplate;

    private String mail = "someMail";

    public void sendNotification(String text) {
        List<SimpleMailMessage> messages = new ArrayList<SimpleMailMessage>();
        SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage(this.messageTemplate);
        msg.setTo(this.getMail());//
        msg.setSubject("Subject");
        msg.setText(text);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        messages.add(msg);
        if(!messages.isEmpty()) {
            try{
                this.mailSender.send(messages.toArray(new SimpleMailMessage[messages.size()]));
            }
            catch (MailException ex) {
                throw new NotificationException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

вызываю его в Listenerе jms но кидает exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'original' message argument cannot be null
```

на сколько понял он не видит мой spring template хотя в помке все подключил

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
```